# Designing word frequency for a word-meaning test

Tags: java, android, theory, computation-theory

I am developing a personalized android program that includes "story-reading" and "Word-Meaning Quizes". First of, user takes a test to specify his level. Then he starts reading stories(of that level). He can look up a word from the pop-up dictionary while reading and this word is registered to db as "seen". After reading some stories, he goes to take a word quiz. This is where my question comes forward. Word-meaning questions must be asked to the user from the words he had seen in the stories and words he hasnt seen of his level. How can I calculate word-meaning question frequency?

I am using Item Response Theory to estimate user's level of cognition.

Comment: Count the number of times the word appears?

Comment: @CumuloNimbus No, calculating the frequency that will drop of a word he has looked up or answered once.

Comment: Take a look on 'priority queue' structure. In Java, there is a  `PriorityQueue` collection that implements it.